# Bind to datacontext in a child view

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a datatemplate for a tabcontrol that I bind to a list of views.
I wish to wrap every view with a BusyIndicator and bind the IsBusy property of the BusyIndicator to the views IsBusy property.
This is the template:

```
 <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}"  x:Name="TabControlViews">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- this is the header template-->
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
        <DataTemplate>
            <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding DataContext.IsBusy, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContentControl}}">
                <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
                    <TextBlock Text="Vent venligst ..." VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding View}"/>
            </xctk:BusyIndicator>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

And this is the viewmodel for each tab

```
public class TabViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ContentControl _view;
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ContentControl View
    {
        get { return _view; }
        set { _view = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
    }

    public ViewType ViewTypeToLoadType { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

So the path to the property I want to bind to is properly:
ContentControl.DataContext.View.DataContext.Isbusy

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that? This is WPF... we work with *data*, not *UI controls*. Just add your `IsBusy` property to the view model, where it belongs. The only job the view model has is to *provide all of the data required in the view*. If your requirement is that you display a busy indicator when busy, then that property is required in the view model.

It's just like any other piece of data... you need to display a person?.. put it in the view model... you need to display an address?.. put it in the view model... you need to display a busy indicator?.. put it in the view model.

Furthermore, if you put your `IsBusy` property in the view model, then you won't need to ask how to bind it to the UI, because it will just as easy as binding any other property and your `BusyIndicator` control will just be part of the view:

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, so to answer your actual question... you want to be able to bind to this path: `ContentControl.DataContext.View.DataContext.Isbusy`

As far as I'm aware, you can't bind from a `DataContext` to a view to another `DataContext`... I'm not sure that I even understand this. However, what you *can* do is use a `RelativeSource Binding` to reach the view... try something like this:

```
{Binding DataContext.IsBusy, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourView}}}
```

The only catch with this is that the view specified in the `Binding` has to be a parent or ancestor of the view where the `Binding` is defined.

Comment: It is on the viewmodel but the viewmodel that has the IsBusy property is living on the view loaded on the TabViewModel.View.

Comment: What I have coded is my own replacement for prism regions to have more control over when a view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is working because the datacontext for the datatemplate is a TabViewModel. so we need to bind to the datacontext of the View property to get to the IsBusy property

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding View.DataContext.IsBusy}">
```